# Как правильно передать список обьектов в generic конструктор?

Tags: java, android, generics

Мне нужно создать диалог который в своем конструкторе будет принимать обьекты типа нужного мне интерфейса.

Так как я получаю с сервера список обьектов которые наследуют от нужного интерфейса и передаю этот список в конструктор диалога, но конструктор подсвечивается желтым и говорит, что это не проверяемое условие...

Как это должно правильно работать на практике?

Вот код

Интерфейс

```
public interface IChoseActionElement
{
    String getElementName();
}
```

Класс наследник

```
public class GetSearchGlobalDataContentFlightClasses implements IChoseActionElement
{
    @JsonProperty("FlightClassName")
    private String mFlightClassName;


    public GetSearchGlobalDataContentFlightClasses()
    {
    }


    @JsonIgnore
    @Override
    public String getElementName()
    {
        return mFlightClassName;
    }
}
```

Диалог

```
public class ChoseActionDialog <T extends IChoseActionElement> extends Dialog
{
    private Context mContext;
    private IChoseActionListener mListener;
    private List<T> mChoseElement = new ArrayList<>();
    private View rootView;

    public interface IChoseActionListener
    {
        void onActionClick(IChoseActionElement iChoseElement);
    }

    public ChoseActionDialog(@NonNull final Context iContext, final 
                             IChoseActionListener iListener, List<T> iChoseElements)
    {
        super(iContext);

        mListener = iListener;
        mContext = iContext;
        if (iChoseElements != null && !iChoseElements.isEmpty())
        {
            mChoseElement = iChoseElements;
        }

        initDialog();
    }

}
```

Использование

```
new ChoseActionDialog(
        getContext(),
        new ChoseActionDialog.IChoseActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onActionClick(final IChoseActionElement iChoseElement) {}
        }, 
        ((SearchFlightActivity)getActivity()).getFlightClasses()
).show();
```

И вот так выглядит warning

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну  или просто подскажите как бы вы сделали это?

Comment: Вот так можно испекцию заглушить `new ChoseActionDialog<?>`,
а чтобы было правильно, нужно вместо `?` указать нужный тип

Comment: Похоже, что дженерик вам тут вообще не нужен. Просто сделайте у коллекции тип `List<IChoseActionElement>`.

Comment: @eugeneek как раз нет... попробуйте присвоить списку с интерфейсами список обьектов который реализует этот интерфейс... не получится. В список можно только добавлять обьекты реализующие этот интерфейс, но не присваивать списку список. Запутано вышло, но думаю вы поняли что я имею ввиду

Comment: @v.andrikeev не совсем понял что вы имели ввиду, можете показать?

Comment: Да, я понял, что вы имели ввиду. Но ведь в этом случае можно не приравнивать один список к другому, а сделать `addAll()`. Просто я не вижу необходимости в дженериках, если есть общий интерфейс.

Comment: @eugeneek тоже как бы правильно все, но `addAll()` возвращает булеан, соответственно я не могу в конструктор передать такое `new ArrayList<>().addAll(((SearchFlightActivity) getActivity()).getFlightClasses());` потому, что мне в конструкторе нужен список а не булеан. Значит мне нужно перед тем как передать  определить этот список вот так `ArrayList<IChoseActionElement> actionElements =  new ArrayList<>();
   actionElements.addAll(((SearchFlightActivity) getActivity()).getFlightClasses());` и передать его по имени... А это как минимум лишние строчки кода.. А с дженериками я могу передать сразу

Comment: А какой тип возвращает `((SearchFlightActivity) getActivity()).getFlightClasses()`?

Comment: @eugeneek Возвращает тип который наследует от `IChoseActionElement` интерфейса

Comment: Попробуйте `new ChoseActionDialog<>(...).show();`

Comment: @eugeneek вроде как работает... Можете поставить как ответ